# Integration Tests of Spring MVC controller

Tags: spring-mvc, model-view-controller, integration-testing, spring-mvc-test

I have a controller which returns XML data in response of a call. Below is the code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/balance.xml",method = RequestMethod.GET,produces="application/xml")
public AccountBalanceList getAccountBalanceList(@RequestParam("accountId") Integer accountId)
{
    AccountBalanceList accountBalanceList = new AccountBalanceList();
    List<AccountBalance> list = new ArrayList<AccountBalance>();
    list = accountService.getAccountBalanceList(accountId);

    accountBalanceList.setList(list);
    return accountBalanceList;
}
```

accountBalanceList is annotated with xml.The response I am getting from this call is like this

```
<points>
 <point>
  <balance>$1134.99</balance>
  <lots>10000.0</lots>
  <onDate>2012-11-11 15:44:00</onDate>
 </point>
</points>
```

I want to write integration test for this controller call. I know how to test a controller with JSON response but I don't know how to test when the response is in XML.Any help will be appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming you're on `Spring 3.2+` you could use the Spring MVC Test Framework (before 3.2 it was a standalone project, [available on github](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-test-mvc)). To adapt the example from the [official documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#spring-mvc-test-framework):

```
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.*;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.*;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration("test-servlet-context.xml")
public class AccountIntegrationTests {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext wac;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void getAccount() throws Exception {
        Integer accountId = 42;
        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/balance.xml")
          .param("accountId", accountId.toString())
          .accept("application/json;charset=UTF-8"))
          .andExpect(status().isOk())
          .andExpect(content().contentType("application/xml"));
          .andExpect(content().xml("<points>(your XML goes here)</points>"));               
    }
}
```

Verifying the contents of the XML file itself would be a matter of reading it from the response content.

---

**EDIT:** Re: getting XML contents

`content()` returns an instance of [ContentResultMatchers](http://static.springsource.org/spring-framework/docs/3.2.0.RC1/api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/result/ContentResultMatchers.html), which has several convenience methods for testing the content itself, depending on type. Updated example above to show how to verify contents of XML response (**please note**: according to the documentation this method needs [XMLUnit](http://xmlunit.sourceforge.net/) to work)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried `andExpect(content().string())` but couldn't succeed to get the result.i guess i have to try something else though.thanks

Comment: Updated the answer to show how to verify that the response contains expected XML.